# Prime factors with stack implementation in C++

Tags: c++, stack, prime-factoring

Greetings stack overflow, recently run into a problem where my code isn't doing exactly what I intend it to do. My intentions are for the user to input a number and then the program will check for its prime factors, when it finds a prime factor I want it to push the number into a stack. I've tried putting cout statements throughout the program to see if any specific spot isn't working but I haven't found anything yet. I believe I am very close to figuring this out, but I am not sure how to advance from here.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class stack
{
    public:
        static const int MAX = 100;
        stack() { used = 0; } // constructor

        void push(int entry);
        int pop();
        int size() { return used; }
        bool empty() { return used == 0;}

    private:
        int data[MAX];
        int used; // how many elements are used in the stack, top element is used - 1
};

void stack::push(int entry)
{
    data[used] = entry;
    ++used;
}

int stack::pop()
{
    --used;
    return data[used];
}

void primeFactors(stack, int);

int main()
{
    stack primeValues;
    int entry = 0;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer (0 to stop): ";
        cin >> entry;

    if (entry != 0)
    {
        cout << "Prime factors: " << entry << " = ";
    }
    primeFactors(primeValues, entry);

    while(primeValues.pop() != 0) // hopefully continues to pop the prime factors until it reaches zero?
    {
        cout << primeValues.pop() << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

void primeFactors(stack primeValues, int entry)
{
    if (entry == 0)
    {
        return; // terminate when zero is reached
    }
    if (entry == 1)
    {
        cout << entry; // if 1 is reached display one
    }

    while (entry % 2 == 0) // while there is no remainder do the following
    {
        primeValues.push(2); // push two into stack 
        entry = entry/2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(entry); i = i+2) // start looping through numbers to find more prime factors
    {
        while (entry % i == 0)
        {
            primeValues.push(i);
            entry = entry/i;
        }
    }

    if (entry > 2) // if the number is greater than two and doesnt have prime factors push the number
    {
        primeValues.push(entry);
    }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of different numbers and nothing seems to work. I've tried just popping a few times to see if anything was pushed, but it only displayed zero. What am I missing here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason to implement your own stack, rather than just using `std::stack`?

Comment: This is a school assignment so the criteria is very specific. We were actually not told that std::stack was a thing either.

Comment: In your `push` member function you should probably check to make sure the stack isn't "full".

Comment: Consider learning how to use a debugger instead of "I've tried putting cout statements throughout the program", it will surely save you time and you will be able to see the data change as you step from one statement to the next. If a program gives the end result you expect it does not necessarily mean that it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a very simple error. In passing your stack by value to `primeFactors` the stack is copied and the copy worked on. When `primeFactors` finishes, that copy is discarded, and your original empty stack is left.

Taking advantage of C++ templates:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T, unsigned int MAX>
class stack {
    private:
    T data[MAX] = { 0 };
    unsigned int used = 0;

    public:
    stack() : used(0) {}

    void push(T entry) {
        if (used <= MAX - 1) {
            data[used] = entry;
            used += 1;
        }
    }

    T pop() {
        used -= 1;
        return data[used];
    }

    unsigned int size() const {
        return used;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return used == 0;
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned int MAX>
void primeFactors(stack<T, MAX>&, int);

int main() {
    stack<int, 100> primeValues;
    int entry = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter a positive integer (0 to stop): ";
    std::cin >> entry;

    if (entry == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    primeFactors(primeValues, entry);

    while (!primeValues.empty()) {
        std::cout << primeValues.pop() << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, unsigned int MAX>
void primeFactors(stack<T, MAX>& primeValues, int entry) {
    if (entry == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (entry == 1) {
        std::cout << entry << std::endl;
    }

    while (entry % 2 == 0) {
        primeValues.push(2);
        entry /= 2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= std::sqrt(entry); i += 2) {
        while (entry % i == 0) {
            primeValues.push(i);
            entry /= i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, knew it would be something small like that. Noted that it needs to be passed by reference for next time!